# Using Selenium to Retrieve data

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I've been teaching myself Python and Selenium to automate a claim submission.  I've managed to stumble through with lots searching and trial and error.  However, I haven't been able to solve this last step. After the claim is submitted a claim number is generated:

<div class="zclip-target" id="claim-number">**484508-638544**</div>

I haven't been able to figure out how to retrieve this value. To no avail I tried:

claim_number=claim_number_element.getAttribute('value')

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

P.S. there is also a button which copies that value to the clipboard.  So if there is an easy way to grab the data from the clipboard that is another solution.

Comment: .text or .getText() would be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with **python** and **selenium**, it's a bit incorrect api for driver instance in selenium python library:

```
claim_number=claim_number_element.getAttribute('value')
```

try that:

```
claim_number=claim_number_element.get_attribute('value')
```

or

```
claim_number=claim_number_element.text
```

Comment: @LabanCabrera please, confirm the answer like solved